# run shell script with arguments manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I need to get three arguments by test.ksh script
as the following

```
  ./test.ksh 12 34 AN
```

is it possible to set the argument by counter for example ?

```
for get_arg 1 2 3
do
my_array[get_arg]=$$get_arg 

print ${my_array[get_arg]}
done
```

in this example I want to get three arguments from the user by loop counter "$$get_arg"
in place of $1 $2 $3

is it possible? and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_array=("$@")

for i in 0 1 2
do
    echo "${my_array[$i]}"
done
```

This assigns *all* the arguments to array `my_array`; the loop then selects the first three arguments for echoing.

If you're sure you want the first three arguments in the array, you could use:

```
my_array=("$1" "$2" "$3")
```

If you want the 3 arguments at positions 1, 2, 3 in the array (rather than 0, 1, 2), then use:

```
# One or the other but not both of the two assignments
my_array=("dummy" "$@")
my_array=("dummy" "$1" "$2" "$3")

for i in 1 2 3
do
    echo "${my_array[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

bash has a special variable

```
$@
```

which contains the arguments of the script it currently executes. I think this is what your'e looking for:

```
for arg in $@ ; do 
    # code
done
```

Comment: @Sven, you don't even need to specify, `in $@`, in a `for` loop.

Comment: Using plain `$@` is almost invariably wrong.  You should use `"$@"`.  Otherwise, `script 'arg 1' 'arg 2' arg-3` is treated as having 5 arguments, not 3.  And the abbreviated `for arg` notation (which I personally don't like) is a shorthand for the explicit (aka preferable, IMNSHO) notation `for arg in "$@"`.

Comment: `$@` is part of the POSIX standard and is available in all compliant shells, `ksh` included.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
My bad ksh:

```
for arg;do
   print $arg
done
```

Original Post:
Use shift to iterate through shell script parameters:

```
# cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

test run:

```
# ./test.sh arg1 monkey arg3
arg1
monkey
arg3
```

[source](http://shtuff.it/article/19/Iterate-bash-script-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Even you don't need `in $@`, this would work the same:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
for arg; do
    my_array[i]="$arg"
    echo "${my_array[i]}"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

That is,

> if `in words` is not present, the `for` command executes the commands
>   once for each positional parameter that is set, as if `in $@` had been
>   specified.

Comment: not good because I need to insert the args to array ( I use for in 1 2 3 as counters )

Comment: @maihabunash, I was just giving an example. Updated my answer to suit your requirement.